# Unable to default init a custom type

Tags: d

```d
struct Tuple(Types...){
    Types values;
    this(Types types){
        import std.algorithm.mutation;
        foreach(index, ref t; types){
          values[index] = move(t);
        }
    }
    alias values this;
}
auto tuple(Ts...)(Ts ts){
    import std.algorithm.mutation;
    static if(Ts.length == 0){
        return Tuple!Ts(ts); // This is the problem
    }
    else{
        return unpack!(move).into!(Tuple!Ts)(ts);
    }
}
static template unpack(alias f){
    pragma(inline)
    auto into(alias target, Args...)(auto ref Args args){
        import std.conv;
        import std.algorithm;
        import std.range;
        enum s = `target(`~iota(Args.length).map!(i=>text(`f(args[`,i,`])`)).join(",")~`)`;
        return mixin(s);
    }
}
```

Why can I write

```d
auto t = Tuple!Foo();
// but not
auto t1 = tuple();
```

The error is

> constructor meta.Tuple!().Tuple.this default constructor for structs only allowed with @disable, no body, and no parameters

but it doesn't go away if I `@disable this()`. Also `std.typecons.Tuple` also doesn't do this and it seems to work just fine.

```d
auto t3 = std.typecons.tuple();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```d
struct Tuple(Types...){
    Types values;
    alias values this;
    alias expand = values;
    static if(Types.length > 0){
        this(Types types){
            import std.algorithm.mutation;
            foreach(index, ref t; types){
                values[index] = move(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor was the problem. Probably because it would result into `this()` if `Types.length == 0`, which is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, you understanding is correct. Variadic lists auto-expand upon usage and as such, empty variadic list is fully equivalent to "nothing".

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that `tuple` is *not* a type: it is just a helper function that returns a type based on its arguments. Since you gave no arguments, it has no valid type to return, and thus fails to compile.

Comment: It is incorrect. No-argument `tuple` call is legal and it returns `Tuple!()` as type.